# Data can not updated when i submit

Tags: php, laravel

i have table like this
table name is pr_item
i want to update item_code receive from 'un-recevived' to 'received'

I want to update a lot ... one click some item_code updated or bulkUpdate
the updated item code must be the same pr_number
but when i click update button code not working, not show error, not effect anything to database just return redirect back to page

[image]

this is my controller

```
 $item = ItemPR::where('item_code', '=', $item_code)->get();

    foreach($item as $data){
    $items = ItemPR::where('pr_number', '=', $data->item_code)->get();
   $update = $items->update(['receive' => 'received']); 

    }
    return redirect()->back();
```

this is my form action

```
 <form action="{{route('inventory.receivedAll')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              {{ csrf_field() }}
              <input type="hidden" name="pr_item" value="$pr_item">
              <button type="submit">
                  <i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </button>
            </form>
```

this is my routes

```
    Route::post('warehouse-inventory/receivedAll', 'ExpedisiController@receivedAll')->name('inventory.receivedAll');
```

this is ItemPR Model

```
 class ItemPR extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'pr_item';
    protected $primaryKey = 'pr_item';

    public  $timestamps = FALSE;

    protected $fillable = [
        'pr_item', 'pr_number', 'item_code', 'pr_qty','price'
    ];

    public function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\ModelMTOItem');
    }

    public function pr()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\DocumentPR');
    }
}
```

whats wrong in my code ? how to Bulk update status from un-receive to received, Please help, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can update it by directly.Just change as following.

```
$item = ItemPR::where('item_code', '=', $item_code)->get();

foreach($item as $data){
    $items = ItemPR::where('pr_number', '=', $data->item_code)->update(['receive' => 'received']); 
}
return redirect()->back();
```

Answer (score 0):

To update all `ItemPR` that has `pr_item` same as `$item_code` make the column from `receive` to `received`.

In your controller, do as bellow:

`$item = ItemPR::where('item_code', $item_code)->update(['receive' => 'received]);`

Besides, in your form there is a small mistake:

This line:

`<input type="hidden" name="pr_item" value="$pr_item">`

Should be as below:

`<input type="hidden" name="pr_item" value="{{old('pr_item')}}">`

Comment: need looping or not ?

Comment: No, you don't need looping. Just replace your code from controller and place this line.

Comment: and in input type udefined variable $pr_item

Comment: I understand. Updated the answer.

Comment: i have follow all your instruction but still not can

Comment: Are you getting any error? Please share the full code of your controller's `method`

Comment: not getting error ,,

this is my controller code

https://pastebin.com/94cQgkY6

plis help me.. have been 2 days not solved :(

Comment: The route and blade you have shared has no relation with your problem. Can you show the route and blade responsible for your problem.

Comment: Your `$item_code` is the `pr_number` of in the `ItemPR` table. right? if yes then your controller code is perfect to work.

Comment: this is my route

https://pastebin.com/W9SNc0J0

yes ItemPR is Model , the table name is pr_item table

pr_number and item_code in table pr_item

Comment: I have updated my answer of controller code. Please try now. By the way. What is the relationship between `pr_number` and `pr_item`

Comment: pr_number is column in pr_item, not relations